# Java Problem at scanner (Line not found) How do i fix this?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have been doing one of my first java projects and i stuck at a error in a scanner where i ask the user if he wants to continue or not (Y or N) i also have the same error (no line found) on my Query method, but i believe if i can fix the first one the other one can be fixed, my code is big with many classes, but here is the maincode where the error is occuring:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String tmp = "";
        String judgment = ""; // to judge whether running or stopping
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0; // counter

        do{
        System.out.println("Enter the database filename (with file type): ");
        tmp = in.nextLine();
        fileInput(tmp,num);

        ++ num;

        System.out.printf("Do you have another file? Press \"Y\" for Yes and \"N\" for No.\n");
        judgment = in.nextLine();

        }while(judgment.equals("Y") || judgment.equals("y"));

        Output();

        // ask for query
        System.out.println("Do you want to query ? (Y for yes/ N for exit)");
      //  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            judgment = in.nextLine();
        // judgment = "Y"; // set judgment manually

        while(judgment.equals("Y")||judgment.equals("y"))
        Query();

    }

Error:
Do you want to query ? (Y for yes/ N for exit)
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at GradeSystem.main(GradeSystem.java:259)
```

Query:

```
 public static void Query() throws IOException {


            System.out.println("Please input the student ID: ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String ID = "1109853A-I011-0022"; // inputing id manually if i read next line gives me the error of no next line
            for(int i = 0; i < stu.size(); ++i){
                if(stu.elementAt(i).stdid.equals(ID)){
                    for(int j = 0; j < stu.elementAt(i).CourseName.length; ++j){
                        if(stu.elementAt(i).CourseName[j].equals(""))  {continue;}
                        else{
                            System.out.println(stu.elementAt(i).CourseName[j]);
                        }

                    }

                    stu.elementAt(i).GPA = stu.elementAt(i).computeGPA(stu.elementAt(i));
                    System.out.println("GPA: " + stu.elementAt(i).GPA);


                }
            }

    }
```

Output:

```
   public static void Output() throws IOException{

        System.out.printf("What course you want to display?(Insert Course Code):");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String courseName = in.nextLine();

        String[] sr = reader(courseName +".txt");
        student[] std = new student[sr.length-2];

        course cor = new course();
        cor.dataC = sr[0]; //maybe on top
        cor.CourseInfo(cor.dataC); //Gets name and credits
        //   cor.dataC = sr[0]; //maybe on top
        cor.studentsnum = Integer.parseInt(sr[1]); // This method will read the number of students


        for(int counter = 0; counter < std.length; ++counter) {
            std[counter] = new student();
            std[counter].dataS = sr[counter+2];
            std[counter].StudentInfo(std[counter].dataS); // sets surname,given name, id and score

            // while inside the loop it will now check for Highest and lowest score
            if(std[counter].score < course.Low) {
                course.Low = std[counter].score;
            }
            if(std[counter].score > course.High) {
                course.High = std[counter].score;
            }
            //*********************************************************************
            // Still inside we store the information to do a Average Score:
            course.Average += std[counter].score;

        }
        //Outside the loop gets the average
        course.Average /= std.length;

        //display
        display(Sort.sortField(std),cor);

    }
```

Comment: Why are you creating object of Scanner class again , and not using it ?

Comment: @tksilicon  judgment.equals("Y") && judgment.equals("y") , it will never hold true

Comment: if i use the new one or the first one gives me the same error

Comment: but you haven't closed the first one , and created the new one , can you try with commenting out that line Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: i did, same error still :(

Comment: can you please put 
       " while(judgment.equals("Y")||judgment.equals("y"))
        Query(); "  in try catch . 
while(cond){
     try{ 
          *your-code*
       catch(NoSuchElementException e){}
}

Comment: Still the same thing, its only catching the error and exiting, the problem is judgment = in.nextLine();  -> says it does not have a next line (even if i add something after it)

Comment: It actually mean , it doesn't have next line to read (not the next line in code). Does it work fine , if you set judgement manually ? and can you please post Query() method also

Comment: You have `fileInput`, `Output` and `Query` all doing things that we cannot see. I suspect one of those methods is closing system.in. Also, your second while statement, `judgement` never gets updated so it is good that your program breaks before then.

Comment: It works fine if i set manually, but i cant do that later because my code has to read a student id, i added Query in the post

Comment: If you delete the parts we cannot see, then it works fine. You still haven't shown the code is actually closing System.in, or an associated scanner. Include fileInput and Output too.

Comment: Did you close scanner in output() method , can you please post it too ?

Comment: added output method, i think i didnt close it? sorry im really new to java, how can i close it?

Comment: in.close() ;  and please close the scanner that you have created inside the methods .

Comment: You need to be able to make a complete compilable example. You haven't included the source code for `fileInput`. You can close System.in by either calling System.in.close(), by calling in.close(), or by using a try with resources.

Comment: @SarthakGupta that isn't good advice, if you close a scanner associated to System.in, then nothing else can use System.in. Which appears to be the exact problem that op is facing. They have closed System.in which means scanner.nextLine fails with a no such element exception.

Comment: @matt he hasn't closed System.in , i think op should check if System.in hasnextLine()

Comment: @SarthakGupta in the code they have provided they don't close System.in. But closing System.in causes the exact problem they're experiencing, and they are executing code we cannot see.

Comment: yeah i agree , In do while he is moving in.nextLine() to  judgment , and just after that he is again moving to judgment , that could be the issue @GabrielPaes , can you please check the value of "in.hasNextLine()"

Comment: @GabrielPaes I would suggest adding `System.out.println("System.in.available(): " + System.in.available());` after you call `fileInput`. I suspect you'll get an error. If that returns a number (even 0), then System.in is fine.

Comment: when i add after fileInput returns 0, when i add after Output(); it gives me an error

Comment: I found where i was closing System.in, thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided enough code to reproduce the problem.

When you create a scanner with System.in, then scanner.readLine() will block until a newline has been entered. The only condition that newLine will fail is if the scanner has reached the end of input.

If you do.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("waiting");
in.nextLine();
System.out.println("enter was pressed");
```

Everything should work as expected. Ways that we can get an error.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("waiting");
System.in.close();
in.nextLine();
```

Produces:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>       at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
>       at Junk.main(Junk.java:10)

We can check if System.in has been closed by calling System.in.available();

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("waiting");
System.in.close();
System.out.println("System.in.available(): " + System.in.available());
```

Will produce the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
>       at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:165)
>       at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:416)
>       at Junk.main(Junk.java:10)

If you are having trouble trying to find out where System.in is getting closed.

```
System.setIn(new FilterInputStream(System.in){
    @Override
    public void close(){
        throw new RuntimeException("System.in closed!");
    }
} );
```

That will make System.in non-closable. Do that first thing in main, and any attempt to close System.in (via a scanner or otherwise) will give an exception.

Comment: I found one of my classes was closing System.in, Thank you so much @matt !!! sorry for the lack of information my code is big, but i finally fixed!

Comment: @GabrielPaes Glad you worked it out. Part of finding the error is isolating the source. So creating a short compilable example makes it easier for other people to help, and often you'll solve the problem in the process.